# how to get total count of results in queries with group by in hibernate?

Tags: mysql, oracle, hibernate, pagination, group-by

assume that is my model:

```
public class UserActions {
    private int id;
    private String username;
    private String actionType;

    // setter and getters  here
}
```

now i wanna to execute this below query and show the results in the table with pagination:

```
select t.username, t.actionType
  from UserActions t
 group by t.username, t.actionType
```

this is the query result:

[image]

now if i execute this query to get total records count:

```
select count(*)
  from UserActions t
 group by t.username, t.actionType
```

this shoulde be result:

[image]

actually if i want to get total records count, is should execute query like this:

```
select count(*)
from (
select count(*)
from UserActions t
group by t.username, t.actionType)
```

but as you know above query can not be executed, because hibernate does not support sub-queries in `from` clause.

**UPDATE**

i'm confused
i found a query that calculates total count with group by clause:

```
select sum(count(*) - count(*) + 1)
  from UserActions a
 group by a.username, a.actionType
```

and it works properly in oracle but doesn't work in postgres and MySql.

Comment: Hibernate Support with statament?

Comment: did you mean `with` clause? no does not support.

Comment: Why don't you run simple `SELECT count(*) FROM UserActions t` if you want to get a total count ? I don't understand your question.

Comment: because i want to calculate total records count with group by @krokodilko

Comment: Regarding the update `I'm confused i found a query that calculates total count .... it works properly in oracle but doesn't work in postgres and MySql.` - this is because Oracle allows for nesting aggregate functions in group-by queries, see the first example in the documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions003.htm#SQLRF20035) and the description above this example. But this is not a feature of ANSII-SQL standard, other DBMS don't allow for such nesting.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, Hibernate - and also JPA - don't allow for subqueries in FROM clause.

You can use a native query, it should work on most databases, since a subquery in a from clause is a basic SQL construct:

```
@NativeNamedQuery(
   name = "some.name"
   query = "SELECT count(*) FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT username, actionType FROM UserActions )"
)
```

**----------
EDIT 
----------**

After some thought I managed to get it working in Hibernate, `MAX` function does the trick, please try this query:

```
 SELECT count(*) from UserActions 
 WHERE id IN ( 
    SELECT max( id ) 
    FROM UserActions 
    GROUP BY username, actionType 
 )
```

Comment: @Rasool Ghafari I've updated my answer with working HQL query, please give it a try